# Azure storage lifecycle management delete append blob is not deleting

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Recently append blob is supported for azure storage lifecycle management. I implemented to delete all items in a specific container after 20 days of last modification. I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#rules). However I tested several ways, and waited every time for more than 48 hours, it is not deleting the blobs. Perhaps I am overlooking something. This is the setup:

I have a blob container which is called logs. In logs I have append blobs. Everything in this container that is more than 20 days ago modified should be delete.

[image]

This is the code view of what I last tried.

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "PurgeLogData",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 20
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "appendBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "logs/20"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I already tried for the prefix match is:

- logs
- logs/
- nameofstorage/logs
- nameofstorage/logs/
- logs/20

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am running out of ideas how it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Checked the rules in your question, it's ok. To delete all blobs in a container, you can just specify `the container name` for `prefixMatch`. For example:

```
"prefixMatch": [
            "logs"
          ]
```

Here are something you need to check:

1.Are you applying some limitations for the container or blobs? eg. are there any [immutability policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutability-policies-manage?tabs=azure-portal) or [blob leased](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob)?

2.Make sure you're waiting at least 24 hours.

3.For testing purpose, you can create a new container, upload some append blobs, then set lifecycle management rules to delete these blobs after 1 day. I tested it at my side, it can work well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked 1, and there is no policy or lease. Lease state is available and unlocked. Also no policy is applied. for 2, everytime I waited 48 hours, while that is the advise. For 3 I am testing it now, so I will get back to you in 48 hours.

Comment: 48 hours has past, and the test file in the test container I created is still in there, while it had to be delete after 1 day. Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: @Emmie, can you manually remove these files? Just want to make sure the deletion can work. And please also let me know the location of your storage account, and it's not ADLS Gen2, right?

Comment: Yes I can manually remove these files. The location is France Central and the account kind is StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Comment: @Emmie, thanks for the info. I will update this thread if I have some findings.

Comment: Thank you for your help, hopefully someone knows what is going wrong

Comment: @Emmie, I tried creating a storage account V2 in France central, and the life management can work by deleting append blobs. If you're sure the policy is enabled, and no other settings like lease or  immutability policies, I really don't know the reason:(. Maybe you need to raise this issue to support team.

Comment: @Emmie can you find the root cause? if you got it, please share it with us.

Comment: I have not found the root cause. I also tried to create a block blob and create a delete rule, but that is also not deleting.

Comment: @Emmie, could you please create a new storage account and see what happens? I asked my colleague, they also suggest raising a support ticket.

Comment: I just started creating a support ticket, and the diagnostic found an issue, we have to enable "allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account" in networking. Now testing, so if in 48 hours it is successful I will update this issue. Thanks for your help